# GWT: How to calculate the number of fragments

Tags: java, gwt, fragment

From https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/fragment_merging:

> To enable this feature, simply add `-XfragmentCount x` to the GWT compiler command line and the code splitter will try to limit the number of exclusive fragments to x. Here, x is the lower bound on the number of exclusive fragments. The actual number might be greater than x when the compiler decides it might not be beneficial to merge as many split points as suggested.

So I ask, how does one calculate "x" for their app? Is fragmentation simply performed "as needed" by studying the compiler reports, or is there some magical formula/equation or set of factors one should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have X fragments without merge option. Compile with no merge option and with (X - 1) setting and compare the results. Beware that there is a bug which shows left over code to be zero: it's not. Check the output folder for the real size.

Note that you may get fewer than X - 1 fragments if the compiler decides to merge more than one fragment (let's say you get X - 4). You can try to force the issue a bit more and compile with X - 5 option. The compiler will do as you ask it, but chances are that there will be no or very little benefit.

I usually keep this setting at X - 1, and let the compiler decide how many fragments to merge.